# Youtube blocking menus

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

The drop-down menus I have are falling behind the youtube video no matter what I give the z-index to the menu.  A website said using wmode=transparent but that didn't work because youtube discontinued supporting that tag.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube doesn't "block" any tags - when you embed a YouTube video, you control the html that you use to embed it. You are free to add whatever extra params you like.

That said, using wmode=transparent is a bad idea, since it will decrease performance of the swf.

Using wmode=opaque will help a little, but is still not as good as not specifying the wmode (leaving it as the default, which is 'window').

If you do set it to 'opaque', then you should be able to place HTML elements over the video and it should work in most browsers, but may have issues on certain browsers in linux, or if the user has an older flash player version.

Answer (score 2):

If you're embedding the player on your site you need to add a param tag that sets the wmode:

```
<object width="425" height="350">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID"></param>
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param>
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque" 
    width="425" height="350">
  </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the wmode parameter both as a param tag and an attribute to the embed tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error with Flash. If you try to hide the flash video with any means it tends to overlap the existing content and pushes the video window forward.